# Wordpress shortcode in custom post type

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to post a shortcode in a custom post type that has the function to add news but it just keeps displaying the shortcode itself and not the shortcode content.

In my theme's functions.php I have added:

```
add_filter( 'insertPages_init', 'shortcode_unautop');
add_filter( 'insertPages_init', 'do_shortcode' );
```

and the function in my insertpages plugin is as follow:

```
function insertPages_init() {
    add_shortcode('insert', array($this, 'insertPages_handleShortcode_insert'));
}
```

Making a post from the custom type post still just prints the shortcode instead of its content. I can get it to work as i wish using example:

```
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

and that works just fine.

How can I get my custom post type to accept shortcodes?

Comment: Try to call the `insertPages_init ` on the `init` hook.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/enable-shortcodes-in-custom-post-types

Comment: Hi, sorry im new to this, how would i go about that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem on insertPages_init filter, the general form of adding a short code is :

```
function footag_func( $atts ) {
    return "foo = {$atts['foo']}";
}
add_shortcode( 'footag', 'footag_func' );
```

and if you want to load on init action like :

```
add_action( 'init', 'load_footag_shortcode' );

function footag_func( $atts ) {
    return "foo = {$atts['foo']}";
}

function load_footag_shortcode(){
add_shortcode( 'footag', 'footag_func' );
}
```